# Why I am not able to push my project from local host to the github

Tags: git-for-windows

I am just a new to the open source development program and I just learning some basic commands.I then came across this concept of shifting the  from local system to github .For this I used the command

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/KalashJain591/kalash-project-git
```

after that to push the project I used this line of code in the git bash

```
git push origin master
```

Then the following error occured and I am not able to push my project from local host  to github.

Comment: Does `git-askpass.exe` ask for the password when you try to push?

Comment: yes it asked for the password and username ,but after than a message on the command line came that .I have to use token access key instead of simple login according to new norms of github aug 2021 @choroba

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Are you behind any corporate firewall? Does this help at all: https://github.community/t/ive-got-an-error-the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel/197400

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't support password access to git anymore. You have to generate a personal access token and use that instead. See [Token authentication requirements for Git operations](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

Alternatively, you can create an SSH key and use `git@github.com:KalashJain591/kalash-project-git` as the remote's URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but after finding more information about this I came across this basic error of :-"fatal: An error occurred while sending the request." and
"fatal: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
" .After all I am not able to solve this error.can you please help me out or suggest any video solution of this

Answer (score -1):

Do you have your public keys installed in github?
This is for passwordless pushing code to github.

```
Login to github -> Settings -> SSH and GPG keys
```

Comment: Keys are used for `git@github.com` remotes, `https` asks for a password (or token).